# Javascript string replace not working inside loop

Tags: javascript

String replace is not working in javascript

My string = 'Get Flat 50% off on Tees Purchase above Rs. 1200';

output string = 'get-flat-50-percent-off-on-tees-purchase-above-rs.-1200';

**here is my js code.**

```
 var json, xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://www.exmaple.com/api/v1.0/deal/deallimit/6/61f4279fb0cb4d4899810bef06539d06e349",true);   
xhr.onload=function() {
                var response=xhr.responseText;
                var resultValue = JSON.parse(response);
                var dealArray = resultValue['All deals'];
                console.log(dealArray.length);
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dealArray.length; i++)
                {

                  var key1 = 749;
                  var key2 = 29;
                  var orgProID = (dealArray[i]['productid']+dealArray[i]['productkey'])/key2;
                  var cat = dealArray[i]['categoryname'].toLowerCase();
                  var catReplace = cat.replace(" ","-");

                  var pro1 = dealArray[i]['productname'].toLowerCase();
                  var proReplace = pro1.replace('%','-percent');
                  var proReplace1 = proReplace.replace(" ","-");

                  console.log(catReplace+"/"+proReplace1);

                  if (dealArray[i]['price'] !=0) {
                     document.getElementById('appendDeals').innerHTML +="<tr><td class='dealName'>"+dealArray[i]['productname']+ " @ Rs."+dealArray[i]['price']+"</td><td class='buyDeal'>BUY</td></tr>";
                  }
                  else{
                     document.getElementById('appendDeals').innerHTML +="<tr><td class='dealName'>"+dealArray[i]['productname']+"</td><td class='buyDeal'>BUY</td></tr>";
                  }
                }
            }            
    xhr.send(null);
```

But when i check in console log i found

```
get-upto 50-percent off on health & personal care products
```

all the places are not replaced by '-'

How to do this.

Comment: your log does not contain "/" are you sure you are posting correct log?

Comment: Please find the answers below and mark one as accepted if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code isnt working because `.replace()` doesnt do the replacement globally inside the string. You need to set the `g` flag to make it work globally.

Follow this simple algorithm for getting the string converted as you want:

1. Make the whole string `.toLowerCase()`
2. `.replace()` the `%` with `-percent`
3. `.replace()` the space with a `-`, globally

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var myString = 'Get Flat 50% off on Tees Purchase above Rs. 1200';

// apply the algorithm here:
var outputString = myString.toLowerCase().replace('%', '-percent').replace(/ /g,"-"); 

alert(outputString);
```

Readup: [`.replace()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [`.toLowerCase()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `replace` in a global sense e.g.

```
var proReplace = pro1.replace(/%/g,'-percent');
var proReplace1 = proReplace.replace(/ /g,'-');
```

Have a look at [JavaScript Replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

Answer (score -1):

The proReplace.replace(" ","-"); only works for the first occurrence of substring. Take a look at here [Replace multiple characters in one replace call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call)