# How can I replace multiple characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regex with following logic:
1., If string contains `T` replace it with space
2., If string contains `Z` remove `Z`

I wrote two regex already, but I can't combine them:

```
string.replace(/\T/g,' ') && string.replace(/\Z/g,'');
```

EDIT: I want the regex code to be shorter

Comment: Why tou need to combine? Just use `var res = string.replace(/\T/g,' ').replace(/\Z/g,'');`

Comment: @VadimB I can see 2 possible reasons: 1: OP wants the regex code to be shorter, 2: OP wants to store regex in an Object or List of Regex

Comment: @nickzoum shorter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace multiple characters in one replace call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Doesn't seem this even needs regex. Just 2 chained replacements would do.

```js
var str = '[T] and [Z] but not [T] and [Z]';
var result = str.replace('T',' ').replace('Z','');
console.log(result);
```

However, a simple `replace` only replaces the first occurence.
To replace all, regex still comes in handy.  By making use of the global `g` flag.
Note that the characters aren't escaped with `\`. There's no need.

```js
var str = '[T] and [Z] and another [T] and [Z]';
var result = str.replace(/T/g,' ').replace(/Z/g,'');
console.log(result);

// By using regex we could also ignore lower/upper-case. (the i flag)
// Also, if more than 1 letter needs replacement, a character class [] makes it simple.
var str2 = '(t) or (Ⓣ) and (z) or (Ⓩ). But also uppercase (T) or (Z)';
var result2 = str2.replace(/[tⓉ]/gi,' ').replace(/[zⓏ]/gi,'');
console.log(result2);
```

But if the intention is to process really big strings, and performance matters?
Then I found out in [another challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468479/) that using an unnamed callback function inside 1 regex replace can prove to be faster.  When compared to using 2 regex replaces.

Probably because if it's only 1 regex then it only has to process the huge string once.

Example snippet:

```js
console.time('creating big string');
var bigstring = 'TZ-'.repeat(2000000);
console.timeEnd('creating big string');

console.log('bigstring length: '+bigstring.length);

console.time('double replace big string');
var result1 = bigstring.replace(/[t]/gi,'X').replace(/[z]/gi,'Y');
console.timeEnd('double replace big string');

console.time('single replace big string');
var result2 = bigstring.replace(/([t])|([z])/gi, function(m, c1, c2){
         if(c1) return 'X'; // if capture group 1 has something
         return 'Y';
       });
console.timeEnd('single replace big string');

var smallstring = 'TZ-'.repeat(5000);

console.log('smallstring length: '+smallstring.length);

console.time('double replace small string');
var result3 = smallstring.replace(/T/g,'X').replace(/Z/g,'Y');
console.timeEnd('double replace small string');

console.time('single replace small string');
var result4 = smallstring.replace(/(T)|(Z)/g, function(m, c1, c2){
         if(c1) return 'X'; 
         return 'Y';
       });
console.timeEnd('single replace small string');
```

Comment: Likely more efficient too

Comment: `replace(string)` only replaces once. Try with `[T] and [Z] and more [Z]`

Comment: @georg True, So I've added that insight to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Do you look for something like this?

ES6

```
var key = {
  'T': ' ',
  'Z': ''
}
"ATAZATA".replace(/[TZ]/g, (char) => key[char] || '');
```

Vanilla

```
"ATAZATA".replace(/[TZ]/g,function (char) {return key[char] || ''});
```

or

```
"ATAZATA".replace(/[TZ]/g,function (char) {return char==='T'?' ':''});
```

Comment: This is the most succinct and worked great for me with ES6 syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

you can capture both and then decide what to do in the callback:

```
string.replace(/[TZ]/g,(m => m === 'T' ? '' : ' '));
```

```js
var string = 'AZorro Tab'

var res = string.replace(/[TZ]/g,(m => m === 'T' ? '' : ' '));

console.log(res)
```

### -- edit --

Using a dict substitution you can also do:

```js
var string = 'AZorro Tab'

var dict = { T : '', Z : ' '}

var re = new RegExp(`[${ Object.keys(dict).join('') }]`,'g')

var res = string.replace(re,(m => dict[m] ) )

console.log(res)
```

Comment: You can also consider a replacement dict, as in `{T: ' ', Z: ''}` and then `m => replacements[m]`

Comment: Bear in mind that if this is for the web [IE doesn't support arrow functions](https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow)

Comment: @Liam what you say is true , but readability wise es6 looks too much better

Answer (score 1):

**Second Update**

I have developed the following function to use in production, perhaps it can help someone else. It's basically a loop of the native's [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) Javascript function, it does not make use of regex:

```
function replaceMultiple(text, characters){
  for (const [i, each] of characters.entries()) {
    const previousChar = Object.keys(each);
    const newChar = Object.values(each);

    text = text.replaceAll(previousChar, newChar);
  }  
  
return text
}
```

Usage is very simple:

```
const text = '#Please send_an_information_pack_to_the_following_address:';
const characters = [
    {
    "#":""
    },
   {
    "_":" "
    },
]

const result = replaceMultiple(text, characters);

console.log(result); //'Please send an information pack to the following address:'
```

**Update**

You can now use [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) natively.

**Outdated Answer**

Here is another version using String Prototype. Enjoy!

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(obj) {
    let finalString = '';
    let word = this;
    for (let each of word){
        for (const o in obj){
            const value = obj[o];
            if (each == o){
                each = value;
            }
        }
        finalString += each;
    }
    
    return finalString;
};

'abc'.replaceAll({'a':'x', 'b':'y'}); //"xyc"
```

Comment: Bad idea to add it directly to the prototype, since you've replaced the native implementation of `replaceAll` that now exists in modern browsers...

Comment: Yep, don't do that. When I created that function "replaceAll" was not available yet. I updated the answer.