# Regex poor performance when nothing matches

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing

I have a problem with slow working regex, but only in case when the patter doesn't match. In all other cases **performance are acceptable, even if patter matches in the end of text**. I'am testing performance on 100KB text input.

What I am trying to do is to convert input in HTML-like syntax which is using [] instead of <> brackets and translate it to valid XML.

Sample input:

```
...some content[vc_row param="test1"][vc_column]text [brackets in text] content[/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row param="xxx"]text content[/vc_row]...some more content
```

Sample output:

```
...some content<div class="vc_row" param="test1"><div class="vc_column" >text [brackets in text] content</div></div><div class="vc_row" param="xxx">text content</div>...some more content
```

To do this I am using regex:

```
/(.*)(\[\/?vc_column|\[\/?vc_row)( ?)(.*?)(\])(.*)/
```

And I do this in while loop until the patter matches.

As I mentioned before this works, but last iteration is extremly slow (or first if nothing matches). Here is complete javascript I am using:

```
var str   = '...some content[vc_row param="test1"][vc_column]text content[/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row param="xxx"]text content[/vc_row]...some more content';

var regex = /(.*)(\[\/?vc_column|\[\/?vc_row)( ?)(.*?)(\])(.*)/;
while (matches = str.match(regex)) {
    matches = str.match(regex);
    if (matches[2].slice(1, 2) !== '/')
        str = matches[1] + "<div class=\"" + matches[2].slice(1) + "\"" + " " + matches[4] + ">" + matches[6];
    else
        str = matches[1] + "</div>" + matches[6];
}
```

How could i improve my regex "not match" performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split it up in 2 regex. 
One for the start tags, one for the closing tags.

And then chain 2 global `g` replaces.

```js
var str   = '...some content[vc_row param="test1"][vc_column]text with [brackets in text] content[/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row param="xxx"]text content[/vc_row]...some more content';

const reg1 = /\[(vc_(?:column|row))(\s+[^\]]+)?\s*\]/g;
const reg2 = /\[\/(vc_(?:column|row))\s*\]/g;

var result = str.replace(reg1, "<div class=\"$1\"$2>").replace(reg2, "</div>");

console.log(result);
```

Note that those `(.*)` in the original regex aren't needed this way.

Using a nameless function, then it could be done via 1 regex replace.

```js
var str   = '...some content[vc_row param="test1"][vc_column]text with [brackets in text] content[/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row param="xxx"]text content[/vc_row]...some more content';

const reg = /\[(\/)?(vc_(?:column|row))(\s+[^\]]+)?\s*\]/g;

var result = str.replace(reg, function(m,c1,c2,c3){
              if(c1) return "</div>";
              else return "<div class=\""+ c2 +"\""+ (c3?c3:"") +">";
             });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This worked for me but I'm curious the reason of using /s in your answer @LukStorms. I know /s is for whitespaces, but the regex in ClasG answer doesn't use it and the result string is correct, only the performance is slightly worse.

Comment: @sss71 Perhaps it's more of a habbit to do that (not just me). That when one sees a requirement that needs to look for spaces, that using \s does that and also takes care of tabs `\t`. But after all, it's an example and it's up to you to tweak it where needed.  You can simple replace the `\s` by " " ,or `[ ]` (for readability).  I do wonder however if the double replace is slower/faster than the one with the function. Might also be that my solution does slightly less backtracking because it uses `(vc_(?:column|row))` instead of just `(vc_column|vc_row)`.  (as in: What no "vc_"? Next!)

Comment: I did performance test on big amount of data and double replace is about two times slower then single replace with function. ClasG example (with function) is between these two but much closer to double replace. I have measured it using Javascript Performance API.

Comment: @sss71 Thanks for the info. It makes sense that prossing 100k two times comes at a cost. So I kinda expected it to be slower than with 1 regex.  I'll keep that in mind for a next challenge.

Answer (score 1):

How about a replace... Like

```
str.replace(/\[(\/?)(vc_column|vc_row)([^\]]*?)\]/g, function(a,b,c,d) {
    return '<' + b + 'div' + (b==='/' ? '' : ' class="' + c + '"') + d + '>';
    });
```

This matches a tag (start or end) and all attributes, including brackets, capturing everything except the brackets. Then puts it back together in the correct format (`div`s with `class`es).

And the global flag (`/../g`) removes the need for any loops.

```js
var sInput = '...some content[vc_row param="test1"][vc_column]text [brackets in text] content[/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row param="xxx"]text content[/vc_row]...some more content';

console.log(sInput.replace(/\[(\/?)(vc_column|vc_row)([^\]]*?)\]/g, function(a,b,c,d) {
    return '<' + b + 'div' + (b==='/' ? '' : ' class="' + c + '"') + d + '>';
    })
    );
```

Comment: Thanks @ClasG for pointing me using function as second parameter of replace. Both answers worked for me, but LukStorms answer has a little bit better performance in my tests and splitting makes it more readable for my eyes.