# Replacing spaces, colons, comma and semicolons using jquery .replace

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using jquery `.replace(/ /g,"-")` replace any string or text with spaces inside of them with hypen. But what If I have comma, colons or semi-colons inside of them. Is there a way I can add multiple conditions in one line of text.

Sample texts like:

`Accreditation, Awards and Recognition` and converted into `accreditation--awards-and-recognition`

---

`The general criteria for scholarship eligibility include:` into `the-general-criteria-for-scholarship-eligibility-include-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, just add all characters inside a `[]` to detect all of them.

Example:

```
/[ ,"']/g
```

If you want to prevent multiple `-` behind eachother like your second example you can add an `*` behind the `[]`

**Accreditation, Awards and Recognition** will be accreditation--awards-and-recognition

If you use `/[ ,"']*/g` **Accreditation, Awards and Recognition** will be accreditation-awards-and-recognition

Here is a tool to test your regex / learn more: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

This thread will help you

[Replace multiple characters in one replace call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call)

Sample Code:

```
str = "Accreditation, Awards and Recognition";
console.log(str.replace(/,| /g,'-'));
```