# Trouble in vowel elimination

Tags: javascript, string

So I was working on a javascript coding challenge, where I was supposed to eliminate all the vowels in a string, here is my code:

```
function removeVowel(str) {
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === "a" || str[i] === "e" || str[i] === "i" || str[i] === "o" ||
      str[i] === "u" || str[i] === "A" || str[i] === "E" || str[i] === "I" ||
      str[i] === "O" || str[i] === "U") {
      if (i === 0) {
        var temp = str.substr(i + 1, str.length);
        str = temp;
      } else if (i === 1) {
        var temp = str.substr(0, 1) + str.substr(i + 1, str.length);
        str = temp;
      } else if (i === str.length - 1) {
        var temp = str.substr(0, str.length - 2);
        str = temp;
      } else {
        var temp = str.substr(0, i) + str.substr(i + 1, str.length);
        str = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(removeVowel("Cheese!"));
```

The code works fine where the vowels are with consonants but fails to work properly when there are consecutive vowels in a string.

The output of the above code is "Ches!";

Am I missing something?Could someone please guide me?

Comment: can you just use regular expression ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace multiple characters in one replace call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call)

Comment: `str.replace(/[aeiou]+/gi, '')` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your approach (fixed)

**Issue in your approach:**

```
var temp = str.substr(i + 1, str.length);
           ^
           |_ You're losing the first part of your String (0 -> i), so you're assigning the String (i + 1 -> length).
```

After executing the `substring` function, you need to decrement your index `i`.

```js
function removeVowel(str) {
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === "a" || str[i] === "e" || str[i] === "i" || str[i] === "o" ||
      str[i] === "u" || str[i] === "A" || str[i] === "E" || str[i] === "I" ||
      str[i] === "O" || str[i] === "U") {
        str = str.substr(0, i) + str.substr(i + 1, str.length);
        i--;
    }
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(removeVowel("Cheese!"));
```

## Approach with array

```js
function removeVowel(str) {
  var array = str.split('');

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var letter = array[i];
    if (letter === "a" || letter === "e" || letter === "i" || letter === "o" ||
      letter === "u" || letter === "A" || letter === "E" || letter === "I" ||
      letter === "O" || letter === "U") {
        array.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
  }
  
  return array.join('');
}
console.log(removeVowel("Cheese!"));
```

## Approach with Regex

```js
var removeVowel = (str) => str.replace(/[aeiou]+/gi, ""); 
console.log(removeVowel("Cheese!"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for looking so keenly on my code and answering my question in such detail.My first approach was to convert the string into an array but I didn;t know how to do that,that's why I applied the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you're not going with RegEx like the comments said, the problem with your code is that you're removing letters from the word AND incrementing i at the same time. That way, when you get to the first 'e' in 'Cheese', it would remove it and increment i, taking you to the 's' position of the new word 'Chese'. Try using a while loop or just remember to go back one position when you find a vowel.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply regex `/[aeiou]+/gi` to remove all vowels

```js
function removeVowel(str) {
  var str = str.replace(/[aeiou]+/gi, "");
  return str;
}
console.log(removeVowel("ChEese!"));
```

You can [find the regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/RlDA8G/1)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and not making fun of me:)

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeVowel(str)
{
    var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"];
    var chars = str.split("");

    return chars.filter(function(char)
    {
        return vowels.indexOf(char) === -1;
    }).join("");

}
```

Comment: Even if the your code might be a valid solution for the OP question, it would be recommended to describe the purpose of the code snippet instead of only adding code.