# How to replace a ton of words in a string with better performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

Recently, i wrote some code for filtering bad words in a string. And a tons of words are going to be filtered. My code works but the performance is not really well as expected.

Below code is only the demo:

**Method 1:**

```
let list = [ "omg", "bbq", "wth", "hello", "world" ];
let smallString = "wthhello123456worldomg789bbqomgomg";
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  smallString = smallString.replace(new RegExp(list[i], "g"), "***");
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
let list = [ "omg", "bbq", "wth", "hello", "world" ];
let smallString = "wthhello123456worldomg789bbqomgomg";
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  smallString = smallString.split(list[i]).join("***");
}
```

I had also make the performance test with jsperf which comparing with split & join or replace :
https://jsperf.com/split-join-vs-replace-dicky

The test result shows that split & join is faster than replace when replacing a small string. But it will be slow when replacing a large string. (I noted that the result will be changed sometimes)

**What i really want**

I actually needs a stable function to replacing the word with better performance. Any advices ? It can be another method that without using replace or split & join. Thanks a lot

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a single regex to replace all targets in one call:

```
smallString = smallString.replace(/omg|bbq|wth|hello|world/g, "***");
```

If you have to keep the targets as an array, turn it into a regex on the fly:

```
smallString = smallString.replace(new RegExp(list.join("|"), "g"), "***");
```

Comment: The second answer is potentially injectable.  If the targets are coming from user-defined data, this is unsafe.

Comment: @JohnHaugeland unsafe? In what way? What "danger" does it present?