# Is there any way yo make a java script string into an array then change the array values then lastly make it back into a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to have a user inputted string like "hello world".  then take the string and turn it into an array with each letter being a part of the array. then i want to change to the values of the array. then i want to take the array and combine all the parts of the array into a string then output it. so the out put would look like "gwkki qieks" note the replacement values are coming from another array.

Comment: Indeed. You can use `var arr = str.split("")`, which you can then make your changes, then to convert it into an array use `arr.join("")`. There is a probably a similar question already asked before, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's required when you ask that you've attempted to resolve your query and posted the results of that, that you've done a bit of research, and that you clearly let us know what the result is that you're looking for. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment you can use `.split("")` to convert your string into an array of characters. You can then use `.join("")` to convert that back into a string after making any modifications.

For this method I'd recommend using a object as it will act like a hash map, that way you don't need to iterate though all your replacement characters each time:

```js
var str = "hello world";          // Original String 

var map = {                       // Used for char replacement
  'h': 'g',
  'e': 'w',
  'l': 'k',
  'o': 'i',
  'w': 'q',
  'r': 'e',
  'd': 's'
};
 
var arr = str.split("");          // Convert to array of chars

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { // For each char in our array
  if(arr[i] in map) {             // If the char in our map 
    arr[i] = map[arr[i]];         // Then replace it
  }
}

console.log(arr.join(""));        // Join combines all chars to string
```

*Edit:*

As *@noahnu* pointed out you can do this using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/User:wbamberg/Examples_on_top/Array.prototype.map():v2). Instead of a standard for loop you can use:

```
str.split("").map(c => map[c] || c).join("");
```

Or in ES5:

```
str.split("").map(function(c){ return map[c] || c}).join(""));
```

This will make the current character being iterated to be the value `map[c]`, if it is `undefined` that will evaluate to `false` and it will then use `c` instead.

Comment: ...or a one liner which is still pretty readable: `'hello world'.split('').map(c => map[c] || c).join('')`

Comment: @noahnu Yes this can be done in less code. Since OP appears to be a beginner/student I wanted to make this more pseudocode-like so they can more clearly understand how to logically solve their problem.

Comment: yes I figured, that's why I kept it as a comment to show the alternative

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing this – https://www.mehtanirav.com/qwerty-werty/

The letters in a string are mapped to the corresponding keyboard keys and shifted so that Q becomes P, W becomes Q and so on. By storing all of the shifts in a dictionary, we can iterate through the characters of the string and append the corresponding mapped letter to the new string.

```js
const keyboard = {
  q:'p',w:'q',e:'w',r:'e',t:'r',y:'t',u:'y',i:'u',o:'i',p:'o',
  a:'l',s:'a',d:'s',f:'d',g:'f',h:'g',j:'h',k:'j',l:'k',
  z:'m',x:'z',c:'x',v:'c',b:'v',n:'b',m:'n',
  Q:'P',W:'Q',E:'W',R:'E',T:'R',Y:'T',U:'Y',I:'U',O:'I',P:'O',
  A:'L',S:'A',D:'S',F:'D',G:'F',H:'G',J:'H',K:'J',L:'K',
  Z:'M',X:'Z',C:'X',V:'C',B:'V',N:'B',M:'N'
}

function qwertyWerty(str) {
  let newStr = '';
  for(const char of str) {
    newStr += keyboard[char] || char
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(qwertyWerty("hello world"));
console.log(qwertyWerty("Hello World"));
```

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty simple to do this.

1. Create a mapping of your letters to your intended keys. For example, `h` to `g`, `e` to `w` and so on.
2. Now use the `.split` to create an array of characters form the string.
3. Now use the `ARRAY.map(KEY => VALUE)` to create a new array with the new new values of the corresponding characters.
4. Now use the `ARRAY.join("")` to convert the list to a string.

Here is the code snippet. Hope this helps.

```js
var string = "hello world";          // initial String 

var dictionary = {'h': 'g', 'e': 'w', 'l': 'k', 'o': 'i', 'w': 'q', 'r': 'e', 'd': 's'};
 
var old_array = string.split("");          // you'll get an array of characters
var new_array = old_array.map(c => dictionary[c] || c);

var new_string = new_array.join("");
console.log(new_string);        // Join combines all chars to string
```