# React - replace() not working to change symbol to letter

Tags: regex, reactjs, replace

Based on other examples, my regex attempt to replace dashes (-) with letters should work. But it doesn't. I am using React.

I have followed this post ([Replace multiple characters in one replace call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call)) and other outside posts but I cannot get regex to replace dashes (-) with certain letters. The app only has one component, App.js. I have also tried writing the line targetNameDashes.replace(/'-'/gi, letter).toUpperCase(); but it hasn't worked either.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/irene-rojas/brooklyn-react

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

state = {
    names: ['JAKE', 'AMY', 'GINA', 'ROSA', 'CHARLES', 'TERRY', 'HOLT'],
    targetName: "",
    targetNameDashes: "",
    guessRemain: 10,
    lettersGuessed: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    let targetName = this.state.names[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.names.length)];
        this.setState({
            targetName: targetName,
            targetNameDashes: targetName.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/gi , '-').toUpperCase(),
            // The flags 'g' and 'i' are for global search and case insensitive search
        });
        console.log(targetName);
}

onKeyUp = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let letter = event.key.toUpperCase();
    let targetName = this.state.targetName;
    let guessRemain = this.state.guessRemain;
    let lettersGuessed = this.state.lettersGuessed;

    if (letter) {
        this.setState({
            guessRemain: guessRemain - 1,
            lettersGuessed: lettersGuessed + letter
        });
        // if letter is in targetName, replace dash with letter
        if (targetName.includes(letter)) {
            console.log("yup");
            let targetNameDashes = this.state.targetNameDashes;
            // temporary variable that contains dashes and letters?
            targetNameDashes.replace(/-/gi, letter).toUpperCase();
            this.setState({
                targetNameDashes: targetNameDashes
                // does it need a callback to update?
            });
        }
    }
    if (guessRemain === 0) {
        console.log("too bad");
        this.setState({
            guessRemain: 10,
            lettersGuessed: []
        });
        this.componentDidMount();
    }
    console.log(`${letter} end of onKeyUp`);
}


  render() {
    return (
  <div className="App">

    <div>
        You will be seen by:
        <br></br>
        {this.state.targetNameDashes}

    </div>

    <br></br>

    <div>
        Letters guessed:
        <br></br>
        <input onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp} />
        <br></br>
        Letters guessed in this round:
        <br></br> 
        [ {this.state.lettersGuessed} ]
    </div>

    <br></br>

    <div>
        Guesses remaining:
        <br></br>
        {this.state.guessRemain}
    </div>

  </div>
);
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: There's quite a bit going on in this React Component and your string replace call isn't React-specific, rather it is JavaScript specific. I would break out each piece of this Component and try to understand it in isolation. Its also not entirely clear what the Component is supposed to do.

Comment: It's a hangman-style game, where you're presented with a name that's been hidden as dashes. You then type in letters and if they appear in the name, the corresponding dashes should change to letters. Any additional pointers about where the replace call goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed many issues that I should mention one by one:

1. Move some of the constants out of the state, for example `names`. Setting them in state makes no sense because they will not be changed and re-rendered in UI.
2. You manually called `componentDidMount` at the end of your key up event handler, which is not they way this should be done. Separate the logic that needs to be re-done in a separate utility function (i.e. `gameReset()` and call that instead).
3. The replace logic of the case when `targetName.includes(letter)` is not correct. It doesn't know which indices to replace.

   Think of that this way: your `targetName` was "EVE", you are asking
   a string that looks like "---" to change to wherever "E" is. How can
   it know where "E" is without inspecting the original name? A loop
   would be a better solution.
4. `setState` is asynchronous in nature. You should make use of `prevState` argument and callback method to ensure you are getting the correct states.

Here I have modified your codes and added comments where necessary, hope it helps:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

// moved it outside state
const names = ["JAKE", "AMY", "GINA", "ROSA", "CHARLES", "TERRY", "HOLT"];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    targetName: "",
    targetNameDashes: "",
    guessRemain: 10,
    lettersGuessed: []
  };

  // utility extracted from componentDidMount
  // so that it can be re-used later
  resetGame = () => {
    let targetName = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
    this.setState({
      guessRemain: 10,
      lettersGuessed: [],
      targetName: targetName,
      targetNameDashes: new Array(targetName.length).fill("-").join("") // fill an array with hyphens
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // call the utility
    this.resetGame();
  }

  onKeyUp = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let letter = event.key.toUpperCase();

    // TODO: provide more logic to avoid bad key strokes
    // for example backspace should not count

    if (letter) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => {
          let modifiedNameDashes = String(prevState.targetNameDashes);

          // for each charecter of targetName
          for (var i = 0; i < prevState.targetName.length; i++) {
            // check if this charecter at index i matched the key
            if (prevState.targetName[i] === letter) {
              // if it does
              // remove a hyphen from modifiedNameDashes at that exact index
              modifiedNameDashes =
                modifiedNameDashes.substr(0, i) +
                letter +
                modifiedNameDashes.substr(i + 1);
            }
          }
          return {
            targetNameDashes: modifiedNameDashes,
            guessRemain: prevState.guessRemain - 1,
            lettersGuessed: [...prevState.lettersGuessed, letter]
          };
        },
        // callback after the state update is done
        () => {
          // won
          if (this.state.targetNameDashes === this.state.targetName) {
            console.log("Nice!");
          }
          // lost
          if (this.state.guessRemain === 0) {
            this.resetGame();
          }
        }
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          You will be seen by:
          <br />
          {this.state.targetNameDashes}
        </div>

        <br />

        <div>
          Letters guessed:
          <br />
          <input onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp} />
          <br />
          Letters guessed in this round:
          <br />[ {this.state.lettersGuessed} ]
        </div>

        <br />

        <div>
          Guesses remaining:
          <br />
          {this.state.guessRemain}
        </div>

        <code>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</code>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit 2rl92oz5j]

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I've got a lot of look over.

Comment: Happy to help! Feel free to ask questions if any part of the code needs explaining. If you believe this is the best solution to your problem consider to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
targetNameDashes.replace(/-/gi, letter).toUpperCase();
this.setState({
    targetNameDashes: targetNameDashes
    // does it need a callback to update?
});
```

This is likely the source of your problem with nothing happening - `String.prototype.replace` returns a new version of the string, and doesn't modify the parameter string.

This would at least cause it to update so you can continue to work on the logic here.

```
this.setState({
    targetNameDashes: targetNameDashes.replace(/-/gi, letter).toUpperCase()
});
```

Comment: That's a start, thank you! But now it replaces all the dashes with a matching letter. I guess technically that's what we're telling it to do. So like you said, continue on the logic.