# Is there a better and faster way to replace digits in string by the text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to **efficiently** (one run over the string, not more) replace values of 1,2,3 in a string to their text representation, s.t. one, two, three. What would be the most efficient way in JS for that?

Example:

**Input**: `Old value '2', new value: '1', predicted value: '3'`

**Output**:  `Old value 'two', new value: 'one', predicted value: 'three'`

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
function formatActionInSysHistory(strValue) {
    let dict = {
      1: 'one',
      2: 'two',
      3: 'three'
    }
    foo = strValue.replace(/[123]/g, val => dict[val])
    console.log(foo)
}
formatActionInSysHistory("Old value '2', new value: '1', predicted value: '3'")
```

Comment: Have you tried yourself?

Comment: regular expression....

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for the most efficient way here , if you haven't noticed @DamienAsseya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, if any one needs:

```
function formatActionInSysHistory(strValue) {
    let dict = {
      1: 'one',
      2: 'two',
      3: 'three'
    }
    foo = strValue.replace(/[123]/g, val => dict[val])
    console.log(foo)
}
formatActionInSysHistory("Old value '2', new value: '1', predicted value: '3'")
```

Also more examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regular expression`. Below is an example.

```js
let str = "Old value '2', new value: '1', predicted value: '3'";

const mapObj = {
   1:"one",
   2:"two",
   3:"three"
};

const replaceAll = (str, mapObj) => {
    const re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi");

    return str.replace(re, function(matched){
        return mapObj[matched.toLowerCase()];
    });
}

console.log(replaceAll(str, mapObj));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var demoStr = "Old v1alue '2', new value: '1', predicted value: '3'"

function convertStr(str){
    console.time('convertStr')
     let enNum = ['zero','one','two','three']
     str = str.replace(/(\d)/g,(matched,p1)=>{
        return p1 && enNum[p1]
    })
    console.timeEnd('convertStr')
    return str

}

convertStr(demoStr)
```