# Remove exact part of a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have a string that somewhere contains `x:` how do I remove exactly that part and only that part of the string? 
For example: `Word test description x: 28 cow dog` and I want to return this string but without the x: part.

Comment: `str.replace('x:', '')`?

Comment: @Nick this will work with the example, but if there are several occurences it will only remove one

Comment: @LaurentS. agreed, but OP asks to "remove exactly that part and only that part` which I interpret as meaning there is only one occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to regex it globally like this

```
let test = 'test string x: is this x:'
let removed = test.replace(/(^|\s)x:\s?/g, ' ')
```

Just replace the found with an empty character

To be sure as it was pointed out in the comments I introduced changes to match only is 'x:' is a standalone combination of characters in the string with the space after it is optional which can be seen in the '\s?' part.

Edit: add to support start of the string as well

Comment: What about `matrix:` ?

Comment: PS just a side-note that `\s` is equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`

Comment: What if `x:` is at the beginning of string? ;)

Answer (score -1):

As you can also see in the first comment. You can use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method. So,

```
var str = "Word test description x: 28 cow dog";
str = str.replace("x:", "");
```

First argument of replace takes string to be replaced and second argument takes string to be replaced with.

#### Edit

Although, if you have many `x:` then it will just replace first one. So keep that in mind. Also, if there are limited lets say 2 or 3, you can replace multiple times. Like:

```
str = str.replace("x:", "");
str = str.replace("x:", "");
str = str.replace("x:", "");
```

But, it is not obviously great for unlimited number of `x:`. Still, if very few strings is to be replaced then it will just be great to make simple. Here is the problem asked in [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16577007/10860596) for multiple replace.