# Replace all occurrences of ',' to space in a string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to replace all the occurence of ',' to ' ' and '{' to ' ' and ' }' to ' '.

By using replace, I can only replace the first occurrence of ',' and I want to replace all occurrences.

```js
 const summary_data=[{Geo: "US West", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 65},
    {Geo: "NSU", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 9}, 
     {Geo: "US East", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 3}];
  
       var str="";
        $.each(summary_data, function (key, entry) {
           str += JSON.stringify(entry) .replace(","," ") + "\n";
         });
            console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: To replace all commas `.replace(/\,/g, " ")` to replace multiple `.replace(/[\{\}\,]/g, "")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace multiple characters in one replace call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a regular expression with the global modifier. Use the pipe (`|`) to match either a comma or curly brace.

```
str += JSON.stringify(entry) .replace(/,|\{|\}/g," ") + "\n";
```

```js
 const summary_data=[{Geo: "US West", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 65},
    {Geo: "NSU", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 9}, 
     {Geo: "US East", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 3}];
  
       var str="";
        $.each(summary_data, function (key, entry) {
           str += JSON.stringify(entry) .replace(/,|\{|\}/g," ") + "\n";
         });
            console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a perfect example of answering the question without realizing that OP is already speeding down the wrong path. OP for some reason thinks that they have to remove the syntax characters (`,`, `{`, etc) from an object literal, which is obviously nonsense. And here's the aftermath: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62676212/form-the-the-table-with-json-data

Comment: Crucial reading for everybody who answered this: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Chris G Are you the one who down voted all the others? Just curious.

Comment: @hev1 I was asking Chris G.

Comment: @AttemptedMastery Yes, primarily because these answers (while not wrong per se, if you completely ignore the context) are misleading and if somebody finds them, the wrong approach will perpetuate. Answering a question is about understanding the problem that OP is trying to solve, and every single answers fails at that.

Comment: @ChrisG I do not think that a question asking how to replace all commas and curly braces in a string will perpetuate an incorrect approach. Just because one cannot think of a valid reason for doing something does not mean that there is no use case for it.

Comment: That's true, but why not even mention that OP is pointlessly turning their object into JSON? Also, this question is an obvious duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call

Answer (score 2):

Hey `replace` accepts regex and you can put global flag on it like this:

```js
replace(/,/g, " ")
```

This will replace all occurrences of "," with " "

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var exampleStr = "{example, string}";

// Returns " example  string "
exampleStr.replace(/,/g, " ").replace(/{/g, " ").replace(/}/g, " ");

// Returns "example string"
exampleStr.replace(/,/g, "").replace(/{/g, "").replace(/}/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

`let str = JSON.stringify(summary_data).split(',').join(' ').split('{').join(' ').split('}').join('')`

No regex answer

Answer (score 1):

From the [String.prototype.replace() docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> ... If `pattern` is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced.

To get around this limitation either use `replaceAll()` or a regular expression i.e. `replace(/,/g, ' ')`

Answer (score 1):

[`string.replace(searchvalue, newvalue)`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) where searchvalue can be string or RegExp, and the below example to perform a global replacement.

```
JSON.stringify(entry) 
  .replace(/\,/g, " ") // replace comma's with spaces
  .replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim() //remove extra spaces with only one and trim
  .replace(/[\{\}]/g, "") //To replace multiple
```