# Form the the table with json data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to form the table for the json data.I juct removed the quotation,comma and curly braces.
and tried to add table for geo ,meeting hash  and count.Now able to add only space.

```js
const summary_data=[{Geo: "US West", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 65},
    {Geo: "NSU", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 9}, 
     {Geo: "US East", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 3}];
  
       var str="";
        $.each(summary_data, function (key, entry) {
           str += "<tr><td>\r\n"+JSON.stringify(entry) .replace(/,|\{|\}|\"/g," ") + "\n</td></tr>";
         });
            console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's an array of objects, not JSON. The actual data doesn't contain quotation marks, or commas, or curly braces; those are all part of the object literal syntax used by JS to organize those strings and numbers into a useful data structure. This question is based on profound misconceptions, so it's kind of hard to give a useful answer. HTML table example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qvj15d30/

Comment: I have tried as "<tr><td>\r\n"+JSON.stringify(entry) .replace(/,|\{|\}|\"/g," ") + "\n</td></tr>";

Comment: @Chris G u save me with your fiddle thanks

Answer (score 1):

With keys as headers in the table..

```js
const summary_data = [{ Geo: "US West", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 65 },
  { Geo: "NSU", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 9 },
  { Geo: "US East", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 3 }];
  var val = summary_data[0];
  var table = `<table><tr>`;
  Object.keys(val).forEach(function (key) {
     table += `<th>${key}</th>`;
  });
  table += '</tr>';
  for (var i in summary_data) {
     table += '<tr>';
     var val = summary_data[i];
     Object.keys(val).forEach(function (key) {
        table += `<td>${val[key]}</td>`;
     });
     table += '</tr>';
  }
  table += '</table>';
  console.log(table);
  $('body').html(table);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: HTML string composition is bad practice in general, and especially so for tables.