# Program that changes one letter to another

Tags: javascript

I'm having small issues with what I'm trying to code.
I need my program to change the letters in a word to certain other letters, so for example:

```
const p = 'Help';
console.log(p.replace('e', 'a'))
result: "Halp"
```

My problem with this, is that this code only allows me to change  one of the letters and I would need much more than that, anyway to do a quick fix?

Comment: [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll`)?

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to replace all instances of `e`, or replace other ltters in addition to `e`?

Comment: Other letters in addition to e

Comment: What other letters?

Comment: `['e', 'c', 'd'].forEach(k => word = word.replace(k, 'a'))`

Comment: please add more sample input and output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-do-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @ASDFGerte OP has clarified that that is _not_ what they're looking for, make sure to check out comments before throwing down those dupe votes.

Comment: @CollinD ok, I'll retract the dupe vote. I stopped analyzing, when the question, and existing answers, were in sync. You could use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576983/replace-multiple-characters-in-one-replace-call but ngl, it's still not clear, what exactly is intended.

Comment: Hey guys, one moment just trying all the fixes, going to answer soon

Comment: hey ASDFGerte, that was exactly what I was looking for thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can do a for loop and replace everything you want within the string.